# USB G.Skill KM780 MX Keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard

Is there any method/driver/trick to use my USB G.Skill KM780 MX Keyboard on Ubuntu Linux?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Your keyboard should work as a keyboard without any additional work. Some of the advanced features, might not work. You will not be able to run the configuration software in linux. 
Some built-in functions will still work. The brightness button will work, and you can record on-the-fly macros using the Macro Record (MR) key.

[Source](http://www.gskill.us/forum/showthread.php?p=77629)